# iOS 7 Application Upgrade

Tags: ios

I'm planning to submit an upgrade to my existing application soon but it is not optimized for iOS 7. My question is that can I submit an upgrade to my application using xCode 4.6 or do I need to upgrade my xCode to version 5 compile to iOS 7 and then submit?.

Comment: I'll ask you a question: Does Xcode 4.6 support iOS SDK 7.0?

Comment: yes it support IOS SDK 7.0 in real-time device but xcode4.6 does not support OS7 Simulator if you want to use os7 in simulator then you need to upgrade your xcode to V5